# convert nn.Softmax to torch.tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a softmax function at the end of my Neural Network.
I want to have the probabilities as torch.tensor.For it I am using  `torch.tensor(nn.softmax(x))` and getting error `RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of Softmax`.

May I please know what I am doing wrong here or is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`nn.Softmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Softmax.html#torch.nn.Softmax) is a class. You can use it like this:

```py
import torch

x = torch.tensor([10., 3., 8.])
softmax = torch.nn.Softmax(dim=0)

probs = softmax(x)
```

or, you can use the Functional API [`torch.nn.functional.softmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.softmax):

```py
import torch

x = torch.tensor([10., 3., 8.])

probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(x, dim=0)
```

They are equivalent. In both cases, you can check that `type(probs)` is `<class 'torch.Tensor'>`.